# Responsive form input

Tags: html, css, forms, responsive-design

I have a web page set at a certain restraint for responsive viewing based on screen width. Though, I'm running into an issue where I have a form input set a width of `width:100%` and `padding-left:20px`. The result displays the input field width scaling beyond the width of the body of the webpage by 20px because of the padding.

[image]

Input code:

```
.field {
    outline:0;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    padding-left:10px;
    float:left;
    border: 1px solid #d3d4d5;
    border-right-color: #c2c7ca;
    border-left-color:#c2c7ca;
    color:#3a444f;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    font-size:16px;
}
```

How can I get that extra space at the end of the input field to restrain to the proper width?

Comment: Why not remove the padding?... Can you post your HTML along with this?

Comment: Try border-box: box-sizing for the inputs.

Comment: Without the padding, I get the two bottom input fields in the image. Sure, here's a live preview http://jsfiddle.net/Pxlc/k6SuD/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to add any extra space. You can simply use:

```
input {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
}
```

With the `border-box` option the width setting includes padding and border.